# Unexpected mongo exit code 48 - restarting in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I cannot start my Meteor app using the meteor command. I have tried almost all Meteor reset but all in vain,  but I have manged to run the Meteor project on different ports, but my mongodb instance must be working.

I have tried running Meteor:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB exited because its port was closed, or was already
taken by a previous instance of MongoDB

Check for other processes listening on port 3001
or other Meteor instances running in the same project.
```

Comment: Could you please check if the process `mongod` is running?

Comment: do you mean mongod instance that runs with meteor.... this one has failed but ....... if u run mongo service  seperately, it can run normally..  Even when u run meteor --port 3020 , it also works ... but i dont know why the default meteor command cannot work.......    thank u for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting meteor on a different port is a quick and easy workaround. In my case, I had not instructed any app to run on port 3001, thus via this command, I learned what the culprit was:

```
sudo lsof -i :3001
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
.ruby.bin 2529 daemon   12u  IPv4  22408      0t0  TCP localhost:3001 (LISTEN)
```

Simply kill the ruby server if you want, or simply run your meteor app on a new port.

Comment: Oh thanx guys.. I forgot to appreciate

Comment: @goldsoft25 when you appreciate an answer please mark it the accepted answer and/or upvote it. That benefits everyone.

Comment: @goldsoft25 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

You just need to reset your database

```
meteor reset
```

or

```
 meteor -p 3006
```

Hope this works for you,

Cheers

Comment: But it works perfectly when i change the port  number   for example meteor --port 3010...... this works perfectly well....  Is it my mongo store that is affected or.... pliz help to rectify this because i cannot run any nodejs based app which connects to mongodb using mongo

Comment: actually your mongo instance is running at that port which you are trying to run

Comment: meteor -p 3005 you need to change the port to run meteor server

Comment: yeah thanx.... i was able to do that and it worked perfectly.... but  iam worried about default mongo process app because it has affected all nodejs projects that  use connect-mongo to connect to mongodb database... IT seems iam just ignoring the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to run 2 Meteor apps on the one computer. One on port 3000, the other on port 3001.

Meteor reserves `port` (3000 in this case) and `port + 1` (so, port 3001 too) as stated [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7663#issuecomment-250157690).

So, I changed to port 3010 (`meteor --port 3010`) and that fixed my issue.